# rand() of rows with union queries with limit

Tags: mysql

I want to show values randomly with union of two queries with limit 10.
query:

```
     (SELECT * from table) UNION (SELECT * from table) limit 0,10
```

It shows like this

```
         id  usertype  
          1    4
          2    4
          3    4
          4    4
```

I want to show

```
         id  usertype  
          1    4
          2    4
          3    2
          4    2
```

Comment: Search for ["mysql order randomly"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+order+randomly) and combine.

Comment: means...........

Comment: It means, do some reading. Then use that new knowledge in context of the current problem.

Comment: Add `ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: Why does your desired result have the same IDs but different `usertype`?